# how to load data to ignite cache when there is no ID when Implementing a cacheStore?

Tags: java, oracle, ignite, in-memory-database

I m using ignite cache, I want to cache a view where the id is not relevant so implementing `loadCache` seems to be somehow tricky to me when there is no id!!!

How should I update the example below

```
public class CacheJdbcPersonStore extends CacheStoreAdapter<Long, Person> {
    ...
  // This method is called whenever "IgniteCache.loadCache()" or
  // "IgniteCache.localLoadCache()" methods are called.
  @Override public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<Long, Person> clo, Object... args) {
    if (args == null || args.length == 0 || args[0] == null)
      throw new CacheLoaderException("Expected entry count parameter is not provided.");

    final int entryCnt = (Integer)args[0];

    Connection conn = null;

    try (Connection conn = connection()) {
      try (PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from PERSONS")) {
        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
          int cnt = 0;

          while (cnt < entryCnt && rs.next()) {
            Person person = new Person(rs.getLong(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3));

            clo.apply(person.getId(), person);

            cnt++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new CacheLoaderException("Failed to load values from cache store.", e);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

`clo.apply(person.getId(), person);` this part is the issue in my logic my view doesn't have an ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some unique ID to store data in Ignite. If there is nothing suitable in the actual data, your options are:

- `UUID.randomUUID()`
- Simple counter (`id++`) or `LongAdder`/`AtomicLong` - works only if you are loading from a single node
- `IgniteAtomicSequence` - works across entire cluster